# Prove that $\lfloor x \rfloor \sin (\pi x)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I try to prove that $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor \sin (\pi x)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$. Someone help me, please. I need it tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: What does $[x]$ mean?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: That's the usual notation for $\lfloor x \rfloor$, I think

Comment: [x] = z <=> x - 1 < [x] < x , example [2.7] = 2 , [-1,9]= -2

Comment: Ah, floor.  I guess that would be continuous since $\sin(\pi x)=0$ for $x\in\Bbb N$.  Pretty cool.

Comment: The full square brackets $[x]$ are often used to denote the nearest integer to $x$ rather than the floor.  The comment by the OP should be used to edit the Question, although I don't disagree with closing for lack of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** I assume you can prove continuity at each $x\in(n,n+1)$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$. The problematic points are $x=n$.

So consider the two cases $f(n \pm \epsilon) = \lfloor n\pm\epsilon\rfloor\sin(\pi n\pm\pi\epsilon)$ separately, noting that $\lfloor n+\epsilon\rfloor=n$ and $\lfloor n-\epsilon\rfloor=n-1$ for small $\epsilon$, and show the left and right limits are equal as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: No i can't prove continuity at each x∈(n,n+1), Could you prove it for me?

Comment: I have just learnt analysis for month, and i have so many problem when i learn it  :(

Comment: @TienNguyenQuang for $x\in(n,n+1)$, $[x]$ is constant, so both $[x]$ and $\sin(\pi x)$ are continuous there.